# How is it possible to write a class with two template parameters, where one is a list/array of the other?

Tags: functional-programming, clean-language

I would like to solve this problem in Clean (a language very similar to Haskell):

There is a `class Node t`, with two instances: `instance Node EdgeList` and `instance Node Adjacency`. I would like to create a Graph, which is an array or list of Nodes.

The definition of the `Graph` is:

```
class Graph t1 t2 | Node t2 where
    resetGraph  :: (t1 t2) -> (t1 t2)
    graphSize   :: (t1 t2) -> Int
    ...
```

I would like to write the instances. One with array, and one with list. First, I tried with list, but I get an error: `t2 not defined`

```
instance Graph [t1] t2 | t2 t1 where
    (resetGraph) :: [t1] -> [t1]
    (resetGraph) x = []
    ...
```

It will be called for example like this: `resetGraph listAdj` where listAdj is a list of `Adjacency` Nodes

If I just write: `instance Graph [tt] tt` then I get this error: `Error: this type variable occurs more than once in an instance type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand here is that when you write

```
class Graph l t | Node t where
    resetGraph :: (l t) -> l t
```

you give `l` *kind* `*->*`. Kinds are an abstraction from types. Roughly, kind `*` means you have a 'complete' type. For example, `Int`, `[Char]`, `a -> String` are all of kind `*`. When a type still 'needs an argument', it has kind `*->*`. For example, if you have `:: Maybe a = Just a | Nothing`, then `Maybe Int` is of kind `*`, but simply `Maybe` is of kind `*->*` because it still needs one argument. So, when writing `resetGraph :: (l t) -> l t`, the compiler recognises that `t` is an argument to `l`, so the only way to give `resetGraph` kind `*` (which is necessary for a function), is to give `l` kind `*->*` (and `t` kind `*`).

The second thing you need to know is that types as `[Char]`, `(Int,Int)` and `a -> Real` kan all be written prefix as well: `[] Char`, `(,) Int Int`, `(->) a Real`. You can compare `[]` to `Maybe`: it still needs one argument (here `Char`) to be a complete type. Hence, the *type* `[]` has kind `*->*`. Similarly, `(,)` has kind `*->*->*`, because it still needs two types to be complete, as does `(->)`. (Note: this is documented in section 4.5 of the [language report](http://clean.cs.ru.nl/download/doc/CleanLangRep.2.2.pdf)).

Combining these two, you should write:

```
instance Graph [] Adjacency where
    ...
```

Then, the type of `resetGraph` is resolved to `([] Adjacency) -> [] Adjacency` which is the same as `[Adjacency] -> [Adjacency]`.

For arrays, the prefix notation is `{} Adjacency` for `{Adjacency}`.

By the way: something similar to this is done in `StdEnv` with the class `length`:

```
// StdOverloaded.dcl
class length m :: !(m a) -> Int

// StdList.icl
instance length [] where ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it better now. For some reason I get an error at `instance Graph [] Node where ...`. The error is: `Node undefined`. Node is defined with two instances. And I get no error at `class Graph t1 t2 | Node t2 where`

Comment: @IterAtor You're welcome. Sorry about that, I wrote `Node` where I should have written `Adjacency` or `EdgeList`. (The error tells you that `Node` is not a type.) It is fixed now.

Comment: But I think I should not use `Adjacency` or `EdgeList` directly, because every function which I will need in `Graph` is defined in `Node` (the functions are defined in both instances)

Comment: @IterAtor in that case, you can use `class Graph l where resetGraph :: (l t) -> l t | Node t`, i.e. move the `Node` dependency to the class member (since it doesn't restrict the class variable).

Comment: @IterAtor alternatively, define `class Graph l where resetGraph :: l -> l` and instantiate with `instance Graph [a] | Node a`, depending on whether you want to enforce the `Node` context in the `Graph` class or just in that one instance.